# Wampserver php root relative path not working anymore

Tags: php, path, wampserver, document-root

I am sorry for asking similiar question that have already been asked, but I did not find an answer to my problem.

I was forced to clean-install of OS last week, so I installed the latest Wampserver (3.1.7). I have copied my page to www folder (also databases), but my page is not working anymore. One example of many warnings:

> Warning: include_once(/inc/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...

Folder *inc* is in the root folder of my page and, obviously, *header.php* is in the folder. It works when I leave slash before inc:`include_once(inc/header.php)`, or when I add dot before slash: `include_once(./inc/header.php)`.

So I know how to make it work, but **I do not consider rewriting of all paths in all pages as a solution. It worked perfectly with Wampserver 3.1.0 few weeks ago - so what am I doing wrong?** Has something changed in wampserver, should I set something I do not know about? Thank you for every advice.

Comment: No nothing like that has changed. But where you put your code may be different.

Comment: You should not put anything in the `www` folder thats for WAMPServer's use.

Comment: Do you really mean you copied your databases into the `www` folder? Or do you mean you restorted your database backup using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: _Folder inc is in the root folder of my page_ Do you mean the SAME folder as your page?

Comment: I fail to see how `include_once(/inc/header.php)` ever worked unless the inc folder was in `C:\inc` which of course it should not be

Comment: Riggs: I have copied database folder of my page to wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\data. Yes, proper way would be to export db and then import it, but I am not able to do it anymore becaouse it ran on an onld (no more existing) system. Database is working perfectly, I see everything in phpmyadmin. I have problems with paths in my page.

Comment: RiggsFolly: absolute path: C:\wamp64\www\pagename\inc\header.php, while index.php is in C:\wamp64\www\pagename\

Comment: In that case it should have always been coded as `include_once 'inc/header.php'`

Comment: OK, but I have read something about that (obiously, I am a newbie in page coding), when slash is in the fisrt place, it says - oh, that folder is in the root folder of a page, no mater where the script using that path is located. I do not really understand why it has worked perfectly, and now it is not.

Comment: No **Root folder of the file system** In Windows the root folder is `C:\\` as you have installed WAMPServer on C

Comment: I see your point, but it is like you say, even if I added *C:\wamp64\www\pagename\* as a virtual host? Can be explained, how it is possible, that it worked before?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea